# Add a block invocation to an NSArray?

Tags: ios, handler, objective-c-blocks

I use this code to intercept the method "sendAsynchronousRequest" of the class "NSURLConnection" and try to execute some code in the completion handler.

```
 void (*oldHandler)(id,NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*);

 void myHandler(id block, NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error ) {
       NSLog( @"myHandler: %@ %@", response, error );
       oldHandler( block, response, data, error );
}

…

[object_getClass([NSURLConnection class]) beforeSelector:@selector(sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:)
    callBlock:^( NSURLConnection *url, SEL _cmd, id request, NSOperationQueue *queue, id handler ) {
        struct _block {
            Class isa;
            int flags;
            int reserved;
            void (*invoke)();
        } *blockHandler = (__bridge struct _block *)handler;

        oldHandler = blockHandler->invoke;
        blockHandler->invoke = myHandler;
    }];
```

The problem is that if I have in my application 2 successive calls to "sendAsynchronousRequest" I will loose the invocation of the first one because "oldHandler" will change with the second call of the method.

I have tried to add oldHandler to an NSArray or NSDictionary to identify each invocation in "myHandler" method but it didn't work.

Do you know a solution to my problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just move your code inside of the completion handler?

Comment: I work on a framework, so can't add Completion handler because it is on the client application side

Comment: I think I will create a subclass of NSURLConnection i.e. SubClassOfNSURLConnection and override sendAysnchronousRequest. I will ask users to use SubClassOfNSURLConnection instead of NSURLConnection.

Comment: why not pass `oldHandler` (as a block) as the first argument to `myHandler`, and inside `myHandler` just call the block, and don't need to do any of this crazy stuff with the block header?